# If E and F are finite fields $|E|=q^m$ and $|F|=p^n,$ and an embedding of $E$ in $F$ then $p=q$ and $m\mid n.$

Tags: galois-theory

> If E and F are finite fields $|E|=q^m$ and $|F|=p^n,$ and an embedding of $E$ in $F$ then $p=q$ and $m\mid n.$

My attempt: E and F will have same prime field so p=q. Since F will be extension over E say of dimension k then $|F|=|E|^k$ therefore $m$ divides $n.$ Is my argument correct?

I would like to see any other argument.

Comment: I think it's enough.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is correct.

But you can avoid talking about the prime field:

$|F|=|E|^k$ implies $p^n = q^{mk}$ and this implies $p=q$ and $n=mk$, by unique factorization, since $p$ and $q$ are primes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your argument is correct: 
$$ 
|F|=|E|^k 
\Longrightarrow 
p^n=p^{mk} 
\Longrightarrow 
n=mk 
\Longrightarrow 
m \mid n 
. 
$$